# C++ How to find the biggest key in a std::map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

At the moment my solution is to iterate through the map to solve this.

I see there is a `upper_bound` method which can make this loop faster, but is there a quicker or more succinct way?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The end:

```
m.rbegin();
```

[Maps](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (and sets) are sorted, so the first element is the smallest, and the last element is the largest. By default maps use [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), but you can switch the comparer and this would of course change the position of the largest element. (For example, using [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) would place it at `begin()`.

Keep in mind `rbegin` returns an iterator. To get the actual key, use `m.rbegin()->first`. You *might* wrap it up into a function for clarity, though I'm not sure if it's worth it:

```
template <typename T>
inline const typename T::key_type& last_key(const T& pMap)
{
    return pMap.rbegin()->first;
}

typedef std::map</* types */> map_type;

map_type myMap;
// populate

map_type::key_type k = last_key(myMap);
```

Comment: also it could be worth checking for empty map.

Comment: +1, great answer. After your answer I did some research, and I'd add crbegin to your answer to make it even better (in case we want a const iterator, which might be important in some cases).

Answer (score 13):

The entries in a std::map are sorted, so for a std::map m (assuming `m.empty()` is false), you can get the biggest key easily: `(--m.end())->first`

Comment: end() can't be iterated backwards without an assertion

Comment: @GHuxley - Are you sure your map is non-empty?

Comment: yes. Maybe you're using an STL implementation that doesn't assert for this incorrect use.

Comment: @GHuxley - Sorry, I don't understand why iterating end() backwards is incorrect. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781927), an "iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category" - so why can't it be decremented?

Comment: @user200783- Decrementing of a bi-directional end() iterator only works for some contexts and not others. If you want end() to always work then you need std::prev(m.end()). Refer to notes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev
I'll post it as my own answer to this Qn...

Answer (score 1):

Since the map is just an AVL tree then, it's sorted -in an ascending order-. So, the element with largest key is the last element and you can obtain it using one of the following two methods:

1.

```
    largestElement = (myMap.rbegin())-> first; // rbegin(): returns an iterator pointing to the last element
```

2. 

```
    largestElement = (--myMap.end())->first; // end(): returns an iterator pointing to the theortical element following the last element
```

Answer (score 0):

As std::map is assosiative array one can easily find biggest or smallest key very easily. By defualt compare function is less(<) operator so biggest key will be last element in map. Similarly if someone has different requirement anyone can modify compare function while declaring map.

std::map< key, Value, compare< key,Value > >

By default compare=std::less

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using unordered_map, your keys should be in order. Depending upon what you want to do with an iterator, you have two options:

1. If you want a forwards-iterator then you can use `std::prev(myMap.end())`. Note that `--myMap.end()` isn't guaranteed to work in all scenarios, so I'd usually avoid it.
2. If you want to iterate in reverse then use `myMap.rbegin()`