# what is the iterator type of map<T, U>.begin()

Tags: c++

```
template <class InputIterator, class Distance>
  void advance (InputIterator& it, Distance n);

    InputOutput < Forward < Bidirectional < Random Access

map<int, int> mapInts;
...

std::map<int, int>::iterator it = mapInts.begin();
std::advance (it,5);
```

Q> What is the type of iterator the map.begin returns? InputOut, Forward, Bidirectional?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Map::begin() documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/)

> std::map.begin()
>
> Return iterator to beginning
>   Returns an iterator referring to the first element in the map container.
>
> Because map containers keep their elements ordered at all times, begin points to the element that goes first following the container's sorting criterion.
>
> If the container is empty, the returned iterator value shall not be dereferenced.
>
> **Return Value:**
>   An iterator to the first element in the container.
>
> If the map object is const-qualified, the function returns a const_iterator. Otherwise, it returns an iterator.
>
> Member types iterator and const_iterator are **bidirectional iterator** types pointing to elements (of type value_type).
>   Notice that value_type in map containers is an alias of pair.

**EDIT:** by courtesy of @Andy Prowl:
Per C++ standard § 23.2.4/6

> iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category

Comment: +1, beat me to it. You may also want to quote § 23.2.4/6, saying that in general: "*`iterator` of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category*"