# Check if map entry is last in a range based for?

Tags: c++, for-loop, dictionary, range

I'd prefer to loop through a c++ `map` in the same way as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963910/1382306):

```
for (auto& kv : myMap) {
    std::cout << kv.first << " has value " << kv.second << std::endl;
}
```

Using a range-based for such as this, is it possible to determine that `kv` is the last element in the range?  If so, how?

Comment: If you are not modifying the value. Best to use `auto const&`.

Comment: Could you test if it's equal to myMap.end() - 1?

Comment: `&kv == &*m.rbegin();` Why not use a normal for loop instead? Range for is for when you want to iterator entire collection.

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660195/c-how-to-find-the-biggest-key-in-a-stdmap

Comment: Thank you Loki Astari!  I do need to loop the entire collection jrok.  Thank you all for looking and for great answers!  I'm in the weeds right now, so it will take me a short time to confirm.

Comment: @ooga apologies, didn't see the `-1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the last key in the map and check for it.

```
const auto& lastKey = myMap.rbegin()->first;
for (auto& kv : myMap) {
    if(kv.first == lastKey) {
        std::cout << "The last one" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << kv.first << " has value " << kv.second << std::endl;
}
```

You can also use `std::prev` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev)) if you need the second last or something like  that:

```
const auto& lastKey = std::prev(myMap.end(),2)->first; // gives the 2nd last
```

Comment: i would change `int lastKey` to `const auto& lastKey` to avoid a copy of the key if the key is a complex class and to make the code more generic. +1 if you do this :)

Comment: What about a multimap?