# Finding max key in an unordered_map in c++

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

This question is *similar* to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660195/2172854) question, but I need to find it in an unordered_map (hashMap) instead of a map.  Since the elements in an unordered_map are obviously unordered, I cannot use the logic mentioned in the similar question.

So, is there some way (other than sequential iteration) to find out the maximum key in an unordered_map?  That is, preferably in `O(1)` or `O(logN)` rather than `O(n)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, by its very nature, an unordered map cannot easily deliver its maximum value so, if the unordered map is all you have, you'll have to search sequentially.

However, there's nothing stopping you from providing your *own* class which is derived from (or contains an) unordered map and adding functionality to it. In pseudo-code, a containing class could go something like:

```
class my_int_map:
    unordered_int_map m_map;  # Actual underlying map.
    int m_maxVal = 0;         # Max value (if m_count > 0).
    bool m_count = 0;         # Count of items with max value.

    int getMaxVal():
        # No max value if map is empty (throws, but you
        # could return some sentinel value like MININT).

        if m_map.size() == 0:
            throw no_max_value

        # If max value unknown, work it out.

        if m_count == 0:
            m_maxVal = m_map[0]
            m_count = 0
            for each item in m_map:
                if item > m_maxVal:
                    m_maxVal = item
                    m_count = 1
                else if item == m_maxVal:
                    m_count++

        return m_maxVal

    addVal(int n):
        # Add it to real map first.

        m_map.add(n)

        # If it's only one in map, it's obviously the max.

        if m_map.size() == 1:
            m_maxVal = n
            m_count = 1
            return

        # If it's equal to current max, increment count.

        if m_count > 0 and n == m_maxVal:
            m_count++
            return

        # If it's greater than current max, fix that.

        if m_count > 0 and n > m_maxVal:
            m_maxVal = n
            m_count = 1

    delIndex(int index):
        # If we're deleting a largest value, we just decrement
        # the count, but only down to zero.

        if m_count > 0 and m_map[index] == m_maxVal:
            m_count--
        m_map.del(index)
```

This is a standard optimisation to certain collections in that it provides lazy evaluation of some property while still caching it for speed.

The `O(n)` searching will only ever occur if you delete the last item which is currently of the highest value.

*All* other actions (get-max, add, delete when not the final largest item) keep the maximum value updated with an `O(1)` cost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)